# How do I speed up infoBox.open() on FusionTables layer click?

Tags: javascript, polygon, google-fusion-tables, infowindow, infobox

## Setup

I have [a polygon map of all the Provinces in South Africa](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=16L-UK_1OZxGw6DlKR8V8yP4XZrtmNdOMugRRNrQ#map:id=3).

This is then pulled into a v3 Google Map as a `FusionTablesLayer` as follows:

```
// The Google Map object
map =  new google.maps.Map( mapCanvas, mapOptions );

// The FusionTables layer
layer['provinces'] = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: '*',
        from: '16L-UK_1OZxGw6DlKR8V8yP4XZrtmNdOMugRRNrQ'
    },
    clickable: true,
    suppressInfoWindows: true // Hide the default FusionTables InfoWindow
});
```

Right after that, I attach a `click` event listener to the `FusionTablesLayer`, and build a custom InfoBox object as follows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(layer['provinces'], 'click', function(e){

    /*
        Here I build the infoBox HTML using e.row[]
        eg: html = '<div>' + e.row['Province'].value + '</div>';
    */

    // Attach the infoBox to the click
    infoBox.setContent(html);
    infoBox.setPosition(e.latLng);
    infoBox.open(map);

});
```

After that, I render the layer on the map:

```
// Render the layer on the map
layer['provinces'].setMap(map);
```

All of this works. No problem.

---

## Problem

The click event returns all the columns in the respective row of the FusionTable, and attaches it to the variable `e` above.

Now, each row in the FusionTable has a *very long* KML string - from 114kb to 2.5MB - and this is returned in `e.infoWindowHtml` as well as `e.row['Polygon'].value`.

```
e: (Object)
    infoWindowHtml: "_Very_ long string in here."
    latLng: Q
    pixelOffset: T
    row: (Object)
        Number: (Object)
        Polygon: (Object)
        Province: (Object)
```

The request doesn't take very long due to heavy caching on Google's side, but after clicking on a Province, **it takes almost 5 seconds for the infoBox to pop up**.

---

### tl;dr

The `infoBox.open(map)` method, after clicking on a FusionTables polygon, is very slow. How do I speed it up?

### Update

The data is cached after the first click. Is there a way to cache the data *before* the first click?

Alternatively, is there a way to limit the returned variables attached to `e`, i.e.: remove the 'Polygon' data from the click request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by chance.

You can customise what gets returned by selecting the proper columns in the *Change info window layout...* window.

<kbd>Map tab</kbd> <kbd>Tools `>` Change info window layout...</kbd>

I deselected 'Polygon', and left 'Number' and 'Province' selected.

The columns you select are then attached to `e` in the `click` eventListener:

```
e: (Object)
    infoWindowHtml: "Better string"
    latLng: Q
    pixelOffset: T
    row: (Object)
        Number: (Object)
        Province: (Object)
```

#### Important Note *(here's the luck)*

After selecting the proper columns, you need to change the FusionTable *data* in some meaningful way [to clear the strong caching on Google's side](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=396).

The columns selected in  the `Automatic` tab are returned.
It seems that the `Custom` tab gets ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Its speedy the second time to open the popup, so I presume it gets cached. The KML's are rather large tho, thats your bottleneck - can't you simplify them? For a decent overview you don't need that much detail. That should speed it up. (try replacing one province with just a rectangle and see if that helps)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Simplifying the KML files is - unfortunately - not an option because they get updated by an external source. I'm playing around now, trying to cache the necessary data _before_ the `click` (hence removing the returned `e`, and speeding everything up). Let me know if you have thoughts on this. :{D

Comment: I see that your problem is solved more or less. Just want to add that you can simplify large KML files during updates by using OGR2OGR tool http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html . I'm using this on server side when updating my kml files too. It requires to use some sss technology like PHP.  Cheers!